# How to generate new Python dataframe series based on dataframe values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a data frame as the one generated by the script below - bringing in dataframe "data".

Ideally I would like to generate a new dataframe that combines the id and a sequence of 1 : value.

```py
d = {'id': ['a', 'b','c'], 'value': [1, 2,1]}
data = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
data
```

This means that the ideal output would be:

```py
|------|---------|
|  ID  |  value  |
|------|---------|
|   a  |  1      |
|   b  |  1      |
|   b  |  2      |
|   c  |  1      |
|------|---------|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) by column `value` and reassign values by counter  by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
#if not default RangeIndex
#data = data.reset_index(drop=True)
df = data.loc[data.index.repeat(data['value'])]
df['value'] = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  id  value
0  a      1
1  b      1
2  b      2
3  c      1
```

Alternative solution with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df = (data.loc[data.index.repeat(data['value'])]
          .assign(value=lambda x: x.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1)
          .reset_index(drop=True))
```